# Is it possible to develop 2 maven projects in parallel without clean install every time?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have the following projects which are different projects (different root `pom.xml`):

1. Infra Maven project
2. Using Infra Maven project

When I change something in the infra, I have to `mvn clean install` in order to use the new code in project 2. As far as I have investigated ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222348/how-to-build-project-after-code-changes-without-mvn-clean-install) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853786/maven-2-projects-depend-on-one-another) etc...) there is no other solution for that, **or is there**?

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: I would suggest to combine them into a single multi module project and you can use `mvn clean package` ...apart from that in IDEA it should be handled correctly ...depending what you are doing in Eclipse the workspace resolution you don't need to do a `mvn install` before you can use the code...

Comment: @khmarbaise Combining them into a single project is not an option... Thanks though.

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain your vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to execute the goals `clean install` every time you changed something. You only have to use the "Tool Window" "Maven Projects". There you can use the `+` sign to import the dependency project in your current workspace in intellij. If you change something in project A, it will also be visible in project B without the need of using `clean install` and if project A is a dependency of project B.

Something that can occur is, make sure that the jar of project A is not already in the local mvn repository. That could cause conflicts.

The window "Maven Projects" can be found under View > Tool Windows > Maven Projects. I use Intellij Idea version 2018.1.3 and it works like a charm.

Comment: Did not think of that! thank you, it works, and as a bonus, while debugging I can enter the real implementation and not the bytecode ('Downloaded Sources' did not work).